inserted table for an update trigger along with system versioned table order_kop for SQL_server
I like to check in my update trigger if order_status was set to 90 and it wasn't before (deleted).
But the thing is, it needs to check if order_status was set to 90 and if it never had the status 90 before (system versioned table)
I'm not sure if the system versioned table will already be updated after we are in the update trigger.
This is my current cursor
declare order_kop_cursor cursor for
select i.commission_nummer
      ,i.system
      ,i.order_nummer
      ,i.customer_name
      ,i.customer_email
      ,i.seller
      ,i.store
      ,i.installer
  from inserted
 where i.order_status = 90
   and i.order_status not in
           (
           select okho.order_status
             from order_kop_history_overview okho
            where i.commission_nummer= okho.commission_nummer
              and okho.order_status = 90
           )

Can someone confirm if this will work how I want it to work or tell me how to fix it?

"Can someone confirm if this will work how i want it" you are in the best place to find this out by testing; deploy the changes to your dev environment and then test the different scenarios. We don't have access to your instance or data, and you haven't supplied sample DDL and DML, so it's impossible for us to test for you.

If you have tested it, then presumably it isn't working as you expect (as otherwise you wouldn't be here). Why isn't it working as you expect? Can you provide a [mre]?

Also, declaring a CURSOR in a TRIGGER has a huge "smell" to it. Triggers should have as minimal impact on the transaction as possible, and declaring a trigger to loop through data is far away from achieving that goal.

this is gonna sound really frustrated, and trust me it is, we work with low_code platform and i can't trigger the trigger atm only when i'm on site next week, this is more theoretical prep work  i think i will have when i'm there to maximize the things i can get done

for the cursor, we do it because for every match we find it will do a bit of pl/sql code a curser namely make an api call to 3th party system and we need to build that up for each row we find that meet these requirements

A bit of "PL/SQL"? So are you using a linked server inside the TRIGGER on SQL Server to then do something on an Oracle instance? That definitely doesn't belong inside a trigger. That'll be awful for performance.

i would insert a new row in our api http_queue tabel, who automatically send api casll when on this table every 5 seconds

If you are just inserting into the queue table then why not do that as a set based insert instead of row by agonizing row?

Then, as @SeanLange suggests, just do INSERT INTO dbo.http_queue (<Column List>) SELECT i.commission_nummer, ... FROM inserted i WHERE i.order_status = 90... There's no need to INSERT each of those rows one at a time unless you are intentionally trying to hinder performance.

API calls from triggers are an absolute no/no. Every command will lock up until the API call is finished, causing huge blocking and performance issues. Use some kind of queuing mechanism, like Service Broker or RabbitMQ.
